# Microsoft.XMLHTTP - how to prevent caching?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, windows-desktop-gadgets

So I want to retrieve some JSON data which changes frequently from Windows gadget, by using Microsoft.XMLHTTP ActiveXObject. The problem is that it returns cached version of the page instead of requesting new one.

I have no control over the server, and I can't use usual hack of sending extra parameter because server returns error if I send any parameters.

I've googled this to death and the best information is in [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235464/how-to-make-microsoft-xmlhttprequest-honor-cache-control-directive) question, but none of the answers work for me; I haven't been able to find a way to use ServerXMLHTTP from gadget Javascript. How do I either use ServerXMLHTTP, or prevent caching in a way other than adding random parameter in the URL?

Answer (score 4):

try using POST instead of GET

```
request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
request.onreadystatechange = callback;
request.open("POST", "server.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send();
```

references:
[Prevent Chrome from caching AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463637/prevent-chrome-from-caching-ajax-requests)
and my own experience.

Comment: This is actually a great idea, since POST is usually not cached while GET usually is. Unfortunately in my case the server doesn't accept POST requests. :(

Comment: I used jQuery $.get and was confused why it's not refreshing. I changed to $.post and it started to work so I can confirm it's working. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a random number worked for me in the context of VBA, eg

```
myURL= "http://acme.com/someapp/rest/someendpointurl?randombit=" & Rnd()

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile saveToPath, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If
```

Thank you Sean Cull your solution worked for me in the context of VBA.

(shame I'm not allowed to upvote it so reposting here for reference)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add a random element to the end of your URL ?
your `http://acme.com/someapp/rest/someendpointurl?randombit=20171701143500`

Comment: Nope, the service that I'm implementing verifies all parameters and returns error on random parameter, and I don't have control over the service API.