# json parsing bring same data every time i run the code

Tags: json, excel, vba, github

When I run my code first time after opening excel I get updated and correct data from website but after that I get the same data when I run the code even after 1 hour. the website data change in every 5 minute interval.

I am using excel 2019.
I have downloaded the json converter bas file from github,
(https://github.com/Malekai/Downloading-Data/blob/master/population_data.json).

The code is here....

```
Sub N_Test_33()
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim URL As String, ws As Worksheet
Dim json As Object, r, r1 As String, i, j As Integer
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"
req.Open "GET", URL, False
req.send
r = req.responseText
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(r)

ws.Range("A1").Value = json("filtered")("data")(62)("strikePrice")
ws.Range("A2").Value = json("filtered")("data")(62)("CE")("openInterest")
ws.Range("A3").Value = json("filtered")("data")(62)("PE")("openInterest")

End Sub
```

The code has to be tested between Mon-Friday, 9:30AM to 3:30PM in Indian timing.

Comment: When writing in English, please use capital I instead of small i for denoting "myself".

Comment: Ok I will remember by next time.

Comment: Try adding `req.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-store"` to line before `req.send`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that api, but I'd check to make sure the time-stamp has been updated so that you can be certain the api output is matching the web output. Also, can you be certain that `item 62` will always be referring to the same contract?

Comment: That's because a cached site is loaded - see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614167/microsoft-xmlhttp-how-to-prevent-caching It's not an VBA, Json or Git problem.

Comment: Yes this is most active strick price number. @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Previously:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235464/how-to-make-microsoft-xmlhttprequest-honor-cache-control-directive

Comment: But did you check that the time stamp for the data was actually updated?