# dynamically loading JSON file from javascript

Tags: javascript, json

On my RPi I have an application (developed in C++) running in the background that does some complex mathematics based on some sensor input and produces some result every second. I want to display this data on a website. So I had the idea to have the application produce a JSON formatted file and read that interactively from a javascript script.

The app now produces a file `ModelState.json` in my html directory that looks like

```
{ "x" : -0.886289 , "y" : -0.434931 }
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34579496) answer, I wrote the following html/js

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="ModelState"></p>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        setInterval(showModelState, 1000);

        function showModelState() {
            readJsonFile("ModelState.json", function(ModelStateJson){
                var ModelStateObj = JSON.parse(ModelStateJson);
                if (ModelStateObj.x && ModelStateObj.y) {
                    document.getElementById("ModelState").innerHTML =
                        "x: " + ModelStateObj.x + ", " +
                        "y: " + ModelStateObj.y;
                }
            });
        }
        function readJsonFile(file, callback) {
            let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status === 200) {
                    callback(rawFile.responseText);
                }
            }
            rawFile.send(null);
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

However, what I observe is that the file seems to be loaded once. The data on the webpage doesn't change, while the data in the file does change.
I don't know why. Is it that the `XMLHttpRequest` keeps the file open, such that `onreadystatechange` is not triggered and the callback function is not called again? I would expect the `send` response to finish the request, thus close the file.

Comment: I guess the browser is caching the response, what if you add a timestamp to file e.g.: `\`ModelState.json?time=${Date.now()}\`` for cache bursting purposes.

Comment: Declare `readJsonFile` outside of  `showModelState`. Why are you declaring a function inside another one that's being called every second? Just declare it once and for all, don't redeclare it every second

Comment: @JeremyThille ok, but that doesn't solve my issue

Comment: @cristobal Yes, that fixed it... it a cache issue? weird.

Comment: @JHBonarius the browser will automatically cache files for a given time, that depends on the browser and their internal defaults for files that do not send any cache headers. The problem here is that since the filename does not change, the browser thinks that file has not changed since last fetch, and should just return the data previously fetched.

Comment: @cristobal Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I also found that browsers don't cache POST requests, so changing the method to "POST" also solves the issue.

Comment: Is the file served locally or do you have an server serving the `ModelState.json` file? If you have an server you could check from cache headers sent from developers tools if the browser has once  or via the commandline e.g. `curl -IL -X GET http(s)://.../ModelState.json`.

Comment: If you have an server serving the ModelState.json file, you could tune the server to set the cache header to `no-cache, max-age=0`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [cristobal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620479/cristobal) states in the comments, the problem is caused by the browser caching the read file.

One solution is to confuse the browser with a dynamic url, e.g. by changing

```
readJsonFile("ModelState.json", function(...
```

to

```
readJsonFile("ModelState.json?time=${Date.now()}", function(...
```

An alternative solution (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463939)) is that the browser doesn't cache POST http request methods. Thus you can change

```
rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
```

to

```
rawFile.open("POST", file, true);
```

A third solution (found [here](https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/691922)) is to add a pragma after the line `rawFile.open("GET"...`

```
rawFile.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

More elaborate request headers for cache control can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969579)